# more than 9 subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, charts, matplotlib

Is it possible to get more than 9 subplots in matplotlib?

I am on the subplots command `pylab.subplot(449);` how can I get a `4410` to work?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It was easier than I expected, I just did: `pylab.subplot(4,4,10)` and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do it like this with pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
oFig1 = plt.figure(1)

oFig1.add_subplot(4,4,11)      #(m,n,x) -> x starts with 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10 # number of subplots you want
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = N)
```

Then `len(axes) = N`, meaning you'll have an axis for each subplot to work with.